# Filtering an array of objects - several criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects, like this:

```
var data = [
        {
            name: "block",
            sameid: 500,
            parentid: 62
        },
        {
            name: "circle",
            sameid: 500,
            parentid: 62
        },
        {
            name: "cube",
            sameid: 500,
            parentid: 62
        }            
    ]
```

I need to make a filter on that array to remove objects that have **sameid** and same **parentid**.
But here is a twist that bothers me...
If I get this array of objects:

```
 var data = [
        {
            name: "block",
            sameid: 500,
            parentid: 62
        },
        {
            name: "circle",
            sameid: 500,
            parentid: 62
        },
        {
            name: "cube",
            sameid: 500,
            parentid: 62
        },
        {
            name: "grain",
            sameid: 500,
            parentid: 63
        }
    ]
```

You can see that object with name **grain** (last one), it has different parentid. if that is the case, then nothing should be removed.

I am breaking my head around this one. 
First criteria that I must take into account is a sameid. I should group them by it. Then somehow check for parent ids.

The array can contain many different sameid's and parentid's

UPDATE:
In the first case, where the data has three objects. All should be removed, becouse all of them have same sameid and parentid.

In the second case, where the data has four objects all four should be preserved, since there is one different object with different parentid.

UPDATE **Desired result:**

```
 var filteredObjects = [];
     data = [
        {
            name: "block",
            sameid: 500,
            parentid: 62
        },
        {
            name: "circle",
            sameid: 500,
            parentid: 62
        },
        {
            name: "cube",
            sameid: 500,
            parentid: 62
        },
        {
            name: "grain",
            sameid: 500,
            parentid: 63
        }
    ]
```

In this case, filteredObject will have all values, since there is one different parentid:

```
filteredObjects [{
        name: "block",
        sameid: 500,
        parentid: 62
    },
    {
        name: "circle",
        sameid: 500,
        parentid: 62
    },
    {
        name: "cube",
        sameid: 500,
        parentid: 62
    },
    {
        name: "grain",
        sameid: 500,
        parentid: 63
    }]
```

In this case:

```
var filteredObjects = [];
     data = [
        {
            name: "block",
            sameid: 500,
            parentid: 62
        },
        {
            name: "circle",
            sameid: 500,
            parentid: 62
        },
        {
            name: "cube",
            sameid: 500,
            parentid: 62
        }            
    ]
```

filteredObject will have no values. The data array can contain different sameid as well.

Comment: Can you show desired result?

Comment: Do you have any code that you have tried?

Comment: I am still trying to figure out how to proceed with this... nothing comes up to my mind :(

Comment: Wait, so you only want unique parentid's ?

Comment: Can you show desired results? (2)

Comment: If count of sameid && parentid objects is equal to data.length then set data.length = 0 else do nothing.

Comment: In essence yes. The object MUST have sameid. I am thinking of it as a group criteria. Now for the objects that have are in the same group (sameid) then I must check for the unique parentid.

Comment: So if there is no unique object you want to empty array else you don't want to change anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could build a tree with `sameid` and `parentid`. Then filter the items and return only the one who have two or more `parenid`.

```js
function filter(array) {
    var hash = {};
    array.forEach(function (a) {
        hash[a.sameid] = hash[a.sameid] || {};
        hash[a.sameid][a.parentid] = true;
    });
    return array.filter(function (a) {
        return Object.keys(hash[a.sameid]).length > 1;
    });
}

var data0 = [{ name: "block", sameid: 500, parentid: 62 }],
    data1 = [{ name: "block", sameid: 500, parentid: 62 }, { name: "circle", sameid: 500, parentid: 62 }, { name: "cube", sameid: 500, parentid: 62 }],
    data2 = [{ name: "block", sameid: 500, parentid: 62 }, { name: "circle", sameid: 500, parentid: 62 }, { name: "cube", sameid: 500, parentid: 62 }, { name: "grain", sameid: 500, parentid: 63 }],
    data3 = [{ name: "block", sameid: 500, parentid: 62 }, { name: "circle", sameid: 500, parentid: 62 }, { name: "cube", sameid: 500, parentid: 62 }, { name: "grain", sameid: 500, parentid: 63 }, { name: "library", sameid: 600, parentid: 66 }, { name: "wood", sameid: 600, parentid: 66 }, { name: "water", sameid: 700, parentid: 77 }, { name: "fire", sameid: 700, parentid: 78 }, { name: "orphan", sameid: 300, parentid: 12 }];

console.log(filter(data0));
console.log(filter(data1));
console.log(filter(data2));
console.log(filter(data3));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: You could probably use `some` so you don't need to check every item if there is a difference.

Comment: every works like some. it end if a return value is `false`.

Comment: @NinaScholz thank you for the time :) I have made a small Fiddle with your example, but I have run accross some issues. Would you be so kind to take a look at it?
https://jsfiddle.net/7do8dto0/

Comment: That looks like a different requirement than what you described in your question.

Comment: Thank you @NinaScholz for your time to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ES2015's `Set` structure to find out whether or not you have more than one kind:

```
const parentIdSet = new Set(data.map(item => item.parentid));
console.log(parentIdSet.size); 
// If 1, you only have one parentId in the entire dataset.
```

A Set is a collection of unique values. By putting all of the parent IDs into a Set, all of the duplicate values are removed, and you have only unique values left. If the size of the Set is 1, it means that you only have one parentid in the entire dataset.

Using a set means you can avoid having to store the initial values somewhere and try to compare. The Set does it for you automatically, and with better performance (probably)

Comment: There is a nice concept here, but this alone does not solve the whole question as it does not take `sameid` into account.

Comment: This is a guiding principle. The same can be done for `sameid`.

Comment: Indeed, I was just pointing out that this is not a complete solution and just a neat guiding principle and hence +1. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply iterate through your initial array and build a new one while checking the uniqueness.
It can be done by utilizing `Array.prototype.filter`:

```js
var data = [
  {
    name: "same sameid and parentid",
    sameid: 500,
    parentid: 62
  },
  {
    name: "same sameid and parentid",
    sameid: 500,
    parentid: 62
  },
  {
    name: "different sameid, same parentid",
    sameid: 501,
    parentid: 62
  },
  ,
  {
    name: "same sameid, different parentid",
    sameid: 500,
    parentid: 63
  }
];

var set = {};
var newData = data.filter(function(x) {
  var key = x.sameid + "_" + x.parentid;
  
  if (set[key]) 
    return false;
  
  return (set[key] = true);
});

console.log(newData);
```

Note that this algorithm takes **every first occurence** of same IDs. You can implement another logics, if you need.

Comment: When you have `newData.push()` inside of a `forEach`, you're almost certainly doing it wrong. See `[].filter()` and `[].map()` and `[].reduce()`.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Thanks for your comment. I usually use these functions, and was going to utilize `Array.prototype.every` in my answer. However, I prefered `.forEach` because in this special case it makes code more **readable and understandable**, which is more important in my opinion :)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I have decided to update my answer with `[].filter()` solution :) Please, check this out.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
var distincts = []
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    if (distincts.indexOf(data[i].sameid)==-1)
      distincts.push(data[i].sameid);

if(distincts.length==1){
    var distinctp = []
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        if (distinctp.indexOf(data[i].sameid)==-1)
           distinctp.push(data[i].sameid);
    if(distincts.length==1){
       data.splice(0,data.length)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i have tried to solve your question , you need to add underscorejs for the following code.

```
var data2 = [
    {
        name: "block",
        sameid: 500,
        parentid: 62
    },
    {
        name: "circle",
        sameid: 500,
        parentid: 62
    },
    {
        name: "cube",
        sameid: 500,
        parentid: 62
    },
    {
        name: "grain",
        sameid: 500,
        parentid: 63
    }
]

var backup = data2;
var count1 = 0; 
var count2 = 0;
for(var i = 0; i< data2.length ;i ++){
  for(var j = i+1;j<data2.length ;j++){
    if(data2[i].sameid == data2[j].sameid && data2[i].parentid == data2[j].parentid){
      count1++;
    }
    else if((data2[i].sameid == data2[j].sameid && data2[i].parentid != data2[j].parentid) ||(data2[i].sameid != data2[j].sameid && data2[i].parentid == data2[j].parentid) ){
      count2++;
    }

  }
  if(count2 == 0 && count1 != 0){
    backup = _.reject(backup,function(d){return d.sameid == data2[i].sameid && d.parentid == data2[i].parentid   })
  }
  count2=0;count1=0;

}


console.log(backup,"my new array")
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also look into this approach:

```
data.reduce(function(p, c, index){           
    if (p.length !== index) return [];                              

    if (p.length === 0) {
        return p.concat(c);
    }
    else if (p[0].sameid === c.sameid && p[0].parentid === c.parentid){                              
           return p.concat(c); 
     }           

      return [];
    }, []);
```