# Filter array of object with two criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been breaking head around this problem for some time now, without solution. I have made [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39140297/filtering-an-array-of-objects-several-criteria/39141202#39141202) question regarding the issue, and I got many replies. Unfortunately, replies were not fit for my problem. Probably becouse I did not specify my requirements properly. Thank you all for great answers, I did learn a lot from them.

My task is to filter an array of objects based on two values (**sameid** and **parentid**).

Task:

```
var data2 = [
{ // Case one. Should not return it. There is only one result, with sameid=100 and parentid=10
    name: "one",
    sameid: 100,
    parentid: 10
},
{//Case two: should not return any result, since there both sameid and parentid are the same
    name: "two",
    sameid: 200,
    parentid: 62
},
{//Case two: should not return any result, since there both sameid and parentid are the same
    name: "three",
    sameid: 200,
    parentid: 62
},
{//Case three. Should return all three results. Four and five have identical sameid and parentid. But six has different parentid
    name: "four",
    sameid: 300,
    parentid: 72
},
{//Case three. Should return all three results. Four and five have identical sameid and parentid. But six has different parentid
    name: "five",
    sameid: 300,
    parentid: 72
},
{//Case three. Should return all three results. Four and five have identical sameid and parentid. But six has different parentid
    name: "six",
    sameid: 300,
    parentid: 73
}
]
```

After the filtering is being done, I should have this array of objects:

```
var desiredResult = [
{//Case three. Should return all three results. Four and five have identical 
  sameid and parentid. But six has different parentid
    name: "four",
    sameid: 300,
    parentid: 72
},
{//Case three. Should return all three results. Four and five have identical
 sameid and parentid. But six has different parentid
    name: "five",
    sameid: 300,
    parentid: 72
},
{//Case three. Should return all three results. Four and five have identical
 sameid and parentid. But six has different parentid
    name: "six",
    sameid: 300,
    parentid: 73
}
]
```

Comment: I don't understand how is the output generated, may I have some explanation?

Comment: So is this just you duplicating your own question from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39140297/filtering-an-array-of-objects-several-criteria ? If so, is there any reason you didn't just edit the question for clarity?

Comment: I felt better to make new question to avoid confusion.

Comment: The example looks like you filter only on `sameid = 300`. What exactly is the input (besides the input array) to get this output? I don't see any filtering on `parentid`.

Comment: The only input is the array. I need to filter it based on the existing values inside it (sameid and parentid)

Comment: So what is the logic? I don't see what you want to do?

Comment: I need to filter the data2 array with the rules commented in the code. Desired output should be in desiredResult array.

Comment: @Wexoni - Your'e rules are not understandable. Why is four and five filtered but two and three not? They both are pairs with the same "sameid" and "parentid".

Comment: Two and free have both identical sameid and parentid. In that case they should not be returned. Four, five had same sameid and parent id, but there is six that has also same sameid but different parentid.

Comment: It would have been so much easier to understand if you would have written: *"I want to find the `sameid` values that occur with more than one distinct `parentid` value, and only keep the objects with such `sameid` values"*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want to identify the `sameid` values that occur with more than one distinct `parentid` value, and only list the objects with those `sameid` values.

This ES6 function will do that:

```js
function getChildrenWithMultipleParents(data) {
  // Create a Map keyed by sameid, each with Set of its combined parentids 
  var mp = data.reduce( 
      (mp, obj) => mp.set(obj.sameid, 
                          (mp.get(obj.sameid) || new Set()).add(obj.parentid)),
      new Map());
  // Return the objects that have sameid values with mulitple distinct parentids
  return data.filter ( obj => mp.get(obj.sameid).size > 1 );
}

// Sample data
var data2 = [{ name: "one",   sameid: 100, parentid: 10 },
             { name: "two",   sameid: 200, parentid: 62 }, 
             { name: "three", sameid: 200, parentid: 62 }, 
             { name: "four",  sameid: 300, parentid: 72 },
             { name: "five",  sameid: 300, parentid: 72 }, 
             { name: "six",   sameid: 300, parentid: 73 }];

// Perform filter
var result = getChildrenWithMultipleParents(data2); 

// Output result
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, you would like to have an array that return:

- Have 2 or more items with same `sameid` andalso
- Any other item with the same `sameid` but not the `parentid`

Kindly try - https://jsfiddle.net/bbfh8szj/

```
function GetDisiredArray(Arr) {
    var DisiredArray = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < Arr.length; i++) {
    if (GetIsPotentialItem(Arr, i))
    DisiredArray[DisiredArray.length] = Arr[i];
  }

  $("div").text(JSON.stringify(DisiredArray));
}

function GetIsPotentialItem(Arr, Index) {
    for (var i = 0; i < Arr.length; i++) {
    if (i != Index && Arr[i].sameid == Arr[Index].sameid && Arr[i].parentid != Arr[Index].parentid)
        return true;
  }
  return false;
}

GetDisiredArray(data2);
```

Please let me know if I get you wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
desiredResult = data2.filter(e => e.sameid === '300');
```

Unless you want the filter to be different in other cases, which would make it an entirely new problem

Answer (score 0):

```js
    var data2 = [
    { // Case one. Should not return it. There is only one result, with sameid=100 and parentid=10
        name: "one",
        sameid: 100,
        parentid: 10
    },
    {//Case two: should not return any result, since there both sameid and parentid are the same
        name: "two",
        sameid: 200,
        parentid: 62
    },
    {//Case two: should not return any result, since there both sameid and parentid are the same
        name: "three",
        sameid: 200,
        parentid: 62
    },
    {//Case three. Should return all three results. Four and five have identical sameid and parentid. But six has different parentid
        name: "four",
        sameid: 300,
        parentid: 72
    },
    {//Case three. Should return all three results. Four and five have identical sameid and parentid. But six has different parentid
        name: "five",
        sameid: 300,
        parentid: 72
    },
    {//Case three. Should return all three results. Four and five have identical sameid and parentid. But six has different parentid
        name: "six",
        sameid: 300,
        parentid: 73
    }
    ]
    
    var sameIdBucket = {};
    data2.forEach(function(item){
         if(!sameIdBucket.hasOwnProperty(item.sameid)){
               sameIdBucket[item.sameid] = {uniqueParentIds: [], items: []};
         }
    
         var curr = sameIdBucket[item.sameid];
    
         curr.items.push(item);
         if(curr.uniqueParentIds.indexOf(item.parentid) === -1){
             curr.uniqueParentIds.push(item.parentid);
         }  
    });
    
    var result = Object.keys(sameIdBucket).map(function(key){ return sameIdBucket[key] }).filter(function(item){ return item.items.length > 1 && item.uniqueParentIds.length > 1 }).map(function(item){ return item.items; });
    document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```